# Suppress the output of a Phing target ?

Tags: php, phing

Is there an option to suppress the default output shown when a target is executed in Phing. 
I have a

```
<foreach param="my_param" absparam="my_abs_param" target="my-target">
      <fileset dir="www">
          <include name="lots-of-files-here" />
      </fileset>
</foreach>
```

Where the target does a simple check on each directory which output is not useful at all but prints huge amount of messages telling my-target is called:

```
 > my-target:
[foreach] Calling Buildfile 'build.xml' with target 'my-target'.
```

Is there a way to disable that output?

Answer (score 2):

For an specific target you can't. For the whole execution you can specify silent argument:

```
bin/phing -silent db.wanup.deploy
```

#### Added:

If you want to view few of your echoes, then you should execute it in quiet mode:

```
bin/phing -quiet
```

And set your echo echo level to **warning** or **error**. Control the level at which this message is reported. One of "error", "warning", "info", "verbose", "debug" (decreasing order)

```
<echo level="warning"> món! </echo>
```

#### Quick sample:

With this sample build file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<target name="list">
    <echo>  Hola </echo>
    <phingcall target="mon" />

</target>

<target name="mon" >
    <echo level="warning"> món! </echo>
</target>
```

When we execute phing without arguments, we get:

```
Buildfile: /private/tmp/build.xml

silent execution > list:

     [echo]   Hola

silent execution > mon:

     [echo]  món!

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 0.2197 seconds
```

But when we execute phing with **-quiet** argument (  -q -quiet              be extra quiet ) we get:

```
     [echo]  món!

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 0.1822 seconds
```

Comment: Same as  `phing -S <target name>` right? But this also suppresses normal echo'es. Doesn't it?

Comment: Ah! yes, when you execute phing -help you can see that -silent is the same that -S I always used the word way :)    -S -silent             print nothing but task outputs and build failures. I will modify my anser

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question! Phing does not support supression of specific task output, but foreach/phingcall should not produce this much chatter. This should be fixed in the upcoming 2.9.0, I've created a tracking ticket at http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/1144.

Comment: Is there a way to do this now? I see the ticket is closed.

Comment: I tried command line options, like phing -S <target name>, but this also suppresses the things I want to display, e.g. the echo'es..